chess endgame engine is not working completely correctly
I have proceeded a bit with my goal to obtain a chess-game endgame engine where both players would play fully optimally while there are D<5 pieces on the board so that I can wait for the result.The player who can give a checkmate (be it B or W) should give it as soon as possible while the player who gets inevitably checkmated delays it as long as possible. Draw should be treated reasonably as well. I have obtained this code: https://pastebin.com/FKugyrXW which does 100% this: it computes the minimal number of plies between 2 fen strings which are both descendants of a given initial_fen string. However I'm unable to extract from that functionality the optimal move, it says c1c8 which is not true, c1c6 is OK here,please see the bottom of this page: https://pastebin.com/x8CZ5FwS
Should anyone be interested in a small amount of money for fixing this, contact me at LinkedIn, the name is Jan Pax.The code is included for convenience:
import chess
from collections import deque, defaultdict

def simplify_fen(fen):
    parts = fen.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(parts[:4])  # Normalize FEN string

def generate_moves_and_distances(board):
    initial_fen = simplify_fen(board.fen())
    queue = deque([(initial_fen, 0)])
    distances = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: float('inf')))
    visited = set()

    while queue:
        current_fen, current_depth = queue.popleft()
        
        if current_fen in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(current_fen)
        distances[initial_fen][current_fen] = current_depth

        current_board = chess.Board(current_fen)
        for move in current_board.legal_moves:
            current_board.push(move)
            next_fen = simplify_fen(current_board.fen())
            if next_fen not in visited or distances[initial_fen][next_fen] > current_depth + 1:
                distances[initial_fen][next_fen] = current_depth + 1
                queue.append((next_fen, current_depth + 1))
            current_board.pop()

    return distances

def minimax(board, depth, maximizing_player):
    if depth == 0 or board.is_game_over():
        evaluation = evaluate_board(board)
        if evaluation is None:
            return 0  # Neutrální hodnota pro nedeterminované pozice
        return evaluation

    if maximizing_player:
        max_eval = float('-inf')
        for move in board.legal_moves:
            board.push(move)
            eval = minimax(board, depth - 1, not maximizing_player)
            board.pop()
            if eval is not None:
                max_eval = max(max_eval, eval)
            else:
                max_eval = max(max_eval, 0)  # Neutrální hodnota pokud eval je None
        return max_eval
    else:
        min_eval = float('inf')
        for move in board.legal_moves:
            board.push(move)
            eval = minimax(board, depth - 1, not maximizing_player)
            board.pop()
            if eval is not None:
                min_eval = min(min_eval, eval)
            else:
                min_eval = min(min_eval, 0)  # Neutrální hodnota pokud eval je None
        return min_eval

def find_best_move(board, depth):
    best_move = None
    best_value = float('-inf')

    for move in board.legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        value = minimax(board, depth - 1, False)
        board.pop()
        if value > best_value:
            best_value = value
            best_move = move

    return best_move

 


def evaluate_board(board):
    if board.is_checkmate():
        if board.turn:  # Black's turn, white gave checkmate
            return float('-inf')
        else:
            return float('inf')
    if board.is_stalemate() or board.is_insufficient_material():
        return 0
    return None  # No evaluation, return a neutral score

 

# Main usage
initial_fen = "5k2/8/3K4/6Q1/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"

initial_fen = "8/8/4k3/8/2K5/5Q2/8/8 w - - 0 1"

initial_fen = "8/5k2/8/8/8/8/8/1KQ5 w - - 0 1"


initial_fen = simplify_fen(initial_fen)

board = chess.Board(initial_fen)
AB = generate_moves_and_distances(board)

def print_distances_less_than_two(AB, initial_fen):
    for fen2 in AB[initial_fen]:
        if AB[initial_fen][fen2] < 2:
            print(f"From {initial_fen} to {fen2}: {AB[initial_fen][fen2]} moves")

print_distances_less_than_two(AB, initial_fen)

# Finding best move using minimax
best_move = find_best_move(board, 8)
print("Best move for white:", best_move)

fen3 = "8/5k2/8/8/8/8/8/1KQ5 w - -"
fen4 = "8/8/5k2/8/8/4Q3/8/1K6 w - -"

print(f"Od {fen3} do {fen4}: {AB[fen3][fen4]} moves")


Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

@itprorh66 I know where I've got stuck. It is presumably the function def find_best_move(board, depth):. It is simply not correct and I cannot get it correct. Input is completely given in the code pasted above and output in the link next to this sentence from the question: please see the bottom of this page: . The problem is that the code of the function find_the_best_move outputs c1c8 while correct would be c1c6 on the input from the code given. What shall I write more on my problem to get the code work?

The only advantage of the code is the correct structure AB[fen1][fen2] which gives the minimal number of plies (half-moves) needed to go from fen1 being a descendant of initial_fen to fen2 also being a descendant of initial_fen string.I strongly believe that this structure AB[][] is correct.Now I simply cannot determine the correct shape of the function find_best_move.

What part of DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. did you not understand?

@itprorh66 Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. I didn't post any images and have copied data into the question. I honestly do not know what do you mean.

Your position is mate in 8 moves, meaning it's mate in 16 ply. So your search (minimax) should have a depth of 16 … actually long to compute with a basic minimax. Try alphaBeta with a better evaluation function, move ordering, a transposition table and iterative deepening. It won't affect the optimal solution, only the speed.
